# Pass multiple variables from express to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a list of variables that check against a condition to return as true or false. This works when printing to `console.log` but now I need to render this in a jade template. I am receiving the following error. Where am I going wrong?

```
Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

Jade

```
  #firstlast #{info.success}
```

JS

```
  var fInitialUnderscoreLastName = fInitial + '_' + lastName + email;
  verifier.verify(fInitialUnderscoreLastName, function( err, info ){
    if( err ) console.log(err);
    else{
      var result = info.success;
      console.log( "Info: " + info.info );
    }
  });

  var firstNameUnderscoreLInitial = firstName + '_' + lInitial + email;
  verifier.verify(firstNameUnderscoreLInitial, function( err, info ){
    if( err ) console.log(err);
    else{
      var result = info.success;
      console.log( "Info: " + info.info );
    }
  });

  res.render('index', {
    fInitialUnderscoreLastName: result
    firstNameUnderscoreLInitial: result

  });
```

Comment: didn't you forget to render the view?

Comment: You have to render the view with the variables. Check the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render)

Comment: I need to pass multiple variables back to the view but `info.success` is now out of scope when I render the view. How do I send multiple variables back to the view? I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to render the view like this

```
res.render('yourView',  {
  "info": {"success": info.success, "info" : info.info},
  "variable2": "value",
  "variable3" : "value"
});
```

Edited

```
var fInitialUnderscoreLastName = fInitial + '_' + lastName + email;
var firstNameUnderscoreLInitial = firstName + '_' + lInitial + email;
verifier.verify(fInitialUnderscoreLastName, function( err, info ){
    if( err ) console.log(err);
    else{
      var resultA= info.success;
      verifier.verify(firstNameUnderscoreLInitial, function( err, info ){
        if( err ) console.log(err);
        else{
          var resultB = info.success;
          console.log( "Info: " + info.info );
          res.render('index', {
          "resultA": resultA,
          "resultB": resultB
          });
       }
    });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @QoP, how would I pass multiple variables back then?

Comment: Now you have multiple variables in the example. Wait I'm taking a look at your new edit.

Comment: The problem I am having now is that `var results` is out of scope

Comment: You got it now there! It's not pretty but it should work, you can use async library like async.js to make it fancier and better :P

Comment: Awesome, so would the callback in Jade still remain as `#firstlast #{resultA}`